# Are file level delete permissions enforced in Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, acl

Someone recently raised a bug against a filter driver I've been working on.  They said that I'd made it possible for a limited user to delete Windows files even if they remove the permissions on the file for the user to be able to do that.

I've been looking at it and it's nothing to do with my driver, even a fresh install of Windows allows this.  If you:

1. Logon as a user called "limiteduser" who's a non admin.
2. Create a text file
3. Edit the security for the file
4. Remove inherited permissions and remove "limiteduser" from having any rights to the file.

Once you've done this you find that:

1. You can't changed the contents of the file.
2. You can't rename/move the file or send it to the recycle bin

However you can:

1. Delete the file in explorer with shift-delete
2. Delete the file with cmd.exe (del myfile.txt)

Why is this?  Is deleting files always a property of the parent folder?  And if so why isn't renaming files?

Comment: How is this opinion based?

Comment: Off-topic?  Seriously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this answer isn't complete at all, but I hope it will be helpful nonetheless.

You didn't mention which version of Windows you are using, but as the ones that use any version of the NTFS file system should behave the same I believe it doesn't matter.

The documentation on "File and Folder Permissions" in Windows 2008 Server states that:

> Groups or users that are granted Full Control on a folder can delete any files in that folder, regardless of the permissions protecting the file.

So it would appear that part of the answer to your question:

> Why is this? Is deleting files always a property of the parent folder? And if so why isn't renaming files?

would be that deleting is indeed a property of the parent folder - it looks to me that it's the `Delete Subfolders and Files`special permission that allows you to override the permissions on the file.

Why the "Full Control" permission on the folder won't give rename permission is unclear to me, but my guess is that it's actually only `Delete Subfolders and Files`that has the power to override; to rename a file you would have to have permissions to write too.

I'm guessing that the reason that "Shift-Del" in Explorer and "del" in cmd works and not "Recycle" would be that recycling is a move/change operation.

See this Technet article for reference: [How Permissions Work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Excellent answer, and thanks for finding that snippet from the W2k8 docs.